# Another .Net regular expression to accept anything other than <anytext>

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to match anything other than `<anythext>`. i.e. I need to show an error message if user tries to submit any text within angular brackets.

I have come up with `<[^>]*>` to match any expression like `<anytext>`

I have tried many online regular expression checker and all of them say it will match `<anytext>`

However, when I use negate on the above expression like this `"^(?!<[^>]*>)$"` it does not work as expected.

Could you please point out the mistake ?

Comment: I don't *quite* understand your requirements. Could you please post some examples that should pass the regex, and some that should fail?

Comment: Don't negate the expression.  Match the expression and negate the *result*.  `var invalid = !Regex.Match(regex, text);` Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loookahead isn't correct. Use this regex:

```
^(?:(?!<[^>]*>).)+$
```

`(?:(?!<[^>]*>).)` subexpression means match a character that is not followed by anything in angular brackets. Anchors `^` and `$` will make sure whole line doesn't contain any text in angular brackets.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE5jZ9/2)

Comment: superb Anubhava . You should change your name to "Anubhavi" ;) . May be I should learn some regex from you. I am a beginner.

Comment: You're most welcome Rohit, I found http://regular-expressions.info pretty good site to learn regex